# How to set Protobuf Serialization With Kafka Using C++

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

**USING JAVA**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaProtobufSerializer.class);
properties.put(KafkaProtobufSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
Producer<String, SimpleMessage> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
```

**USING PYTHON**

```
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringSerializer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.protobuf import ProtobufSerializer
topic = 'TEST_PROTO'
schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient({'url': 'http://localhost:8081'})
protobuf_serializer = ProtobufSerializer(test_pb2.Meal, schema_registry_client)
producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers':  'localhost:9092', 'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8'), 'value.serializer': protobuf_serializer}
producer = SerializingProducer(producer_conf)
```

**QUESTION:**
How to get the **Kafka producer instance using schema registry in C++**?

Question is how to add **Confluent Schema Registry** With **C++** Kafka Producer.

Comment: The Python client uses librdkafka C library, so some of those properties are directly transferable. However, you may need to write your own serializer implementations

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer adding properties like we did for other languages did not work for us.  I have tried adding the properties as mentioned above but got error like % No such configuration property: "key.serializer"

Comment: Python has Serializer class not these configuration properties how to SET these configurations in C++

Comment: You'd simply extract that logic into a method that accepts your object and returns a byte array. Then call that as part of the producer send method

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer cannot do that when I try to use kafka_protbuf_console_consumer or Kafka connect to read the data it is giving deserialization error.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to show how you're serializing the data. You cannot simply call Protobuf serialize methods since that doesn't use the Registry at all. You'll need to create the bytes in this format https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: Actually when I save the serialized data using Protobuf json api it works fine.  That means searlization is fine.

Comment: Like I said, that's not going to use the Schema Registry. Therefore the Protobuf consumer deserializer will fail

Comment: OK thanks.  Can I use Avro with C++ along with schema registry.  I know we can but just want to confirm @OneCricketeer

Comment: There is no reason you cannot. The only requirements to use the Registry are an HTTP client and the necessary serialization library. The C bindings for Avro are here - https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/c/index.html

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer  HttpClient?  I have simple C++/C client/producer I was thinking of using this implementation. https://github.com/confluentinc/libserdes. Am I missing something?

Comment: I want to create a simple producer using Avro serialization using c/c++ and able to register that serializer in schema registry... So that we can use Kafka connect consumer using avro and schema from the schema registry.